# How to copy to a formatted image without root privileges?

Tags: filesystems, mount, disk-image

I have formatted an image file using the `mkfs` command, and I would now like to copy files to that image file without root privileges.

I have already tried to mount the image to a local directory, which did require root privileges for some reason. (feel free to comment why)

Is there a widely supported way to copy files into a formatted image without requiring root privileges.

*Edit:* The image is formatted as FAT-32.

Comment: see the `fatcat` for Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Among other things, it's possible to obstruct/overlay filesystem structures with mounts, thus you're not usually allowed to mount anything anywhere without root privileges. The cases where this is done (or seems to be done), there usually is a mount helper involved that runs as root (like fusermount, udisks, ...).

If for some reason using a mount helper is not an option, "a widely supported way to copy files into a formatted image" is to use `mkisofs` which creates an image containing your files, and no root involved anywhere.

It would be entirely possible to implement what `mkisofs` does (and more) in a user space program, but since most people have no issue with mounting instead, I am not sure if such a program exists for most filesystems.

For `ext*` there is `debugfs` which does parts of it.

```
$ echo Hello World > hello.txt
$ truncate -s 100M foobar
$ /sbin/mkfs.ext4 foobar
$ /sbin/debugfs -w foobar
debugfs 1.42.11 (09-Jul-2014)
debugfs:  ls
2  (12) .    2  (12) ..    11  (20) lost+found
debugfs:  mkdir hey
debugfs:  mkdir what
debugfs:  mkdir up
debugfs:  ls
2  (12) .    2  (12) ..    11  (20) lost+found    12  (12) hey   
 13  (12) what    14  (956) up
debugfs:  write hello.txt hello.txt
Allocated inode: 15
debugfs:  cat hello.txt
Hello World
```

So this much seems to work. Automating it is possible (`-f cmdfile` option), but sounds like homework.

Comment: How about a FAT-32 image?

Answer (score 0):

Mounting filesystems is reserved to root by default, because many filesystems allow a user to gain privileges if they control the disk image (e.g. by creating setuid files).

Look for a [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) filesystem implementation that supports the filesystem in your image. FUSE filesystem drivers run in userspace with no privileges, unlike in-kernel filesystem drivers. Unfortunately, not all filesystems have FUSE implementations; in particular, I don't know of any read-write ext4 FUSE implementation.

The path of least resistance is often to access the filesystem image via a virtual machine.